# Is it possible to apply for a UK transit visa in Heathrow on arrival?

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival

My parents are travelling from Bombay to Copenhagen via Heathrow. They are Indian citizens, and have a Schengen visa - type C to enter Denmark. Like a fool I have not applied for a transit visa online.

Is there is a possibility of getting this transit visa on arrival in Heathrow?

They will arrive at Terminal 4 and leave from Terminal 5.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no".  Moreover, they are quite likely to be denied boarding in Bombay if they don't have the appropriate visa for the UK.  In order to transfer from T4 to T5, they will also need to exit the airport, which makes the matters even more complicated.  Your only option is to try to use some kind of "urgent" service is one is available.

Comment: @AleksG There are airside "flight connections" buses at Heathrow, so no need to go landside between T4 and T5. Big problem is the visa to board in Bombay, unless they qualify for an exemption

Comment: Your parent's nationality and visa/immigration status in Denmark can make all the difference - what are those?

Comment: Indian passport holders travelling on schengen visa - type C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 9):

No. Your parents will need to get a visa *before* they get to the airport in Bombay. Without one, they won't be allowed to board the flight to the UK.

You can check if you need a visa or not for the UK with the [Gov.UK Visa Check tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa). For your [parents case the answer is they need a visa for transit](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no), even a Direct Airside Transit as they're doing. This is irrespective of the length of the transit, a visa is always required in this situation.

If your parents had a Category D visa for Denmark, then they'd be allowed under the [exemptions](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no) to Transit With Out Visa (TWOV). A Category C schengen visa isn't enough for that though, so they still need a visa.

(As long as they're on one ticket, your parents are fine with only a Direct Airside Transit visa, as their luggage can then be checked all the way through to Copenhagen, and there are Flight Connections buses which'll take them between T4 and T5 airside without passing through immigration. However, if they had two tickets and would need to collect and re-check baggage, then they'd need a landside transit visa)